# removing shadow from colour image (3-channel (jpg) or 4-channel (png))

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to isolate shadows from this image and remove them:

[image]

The reason why I am doing that is because shadow is problematic for my edge detection algorithm.

What should I do to remove the shadow? I haven't done this before, so I do not even know where to start from.

From the similar questions on SO I wasn't able to find anything to help me with my task.

I have the image in both: png and jpg format, so I am not even sure which format to use to start with.

Answer (score 0):

That's a very interesting question.  One option you can try is to divide the RGB values in the image by the grayscale intensity of the image.  There is apparently another method explained here: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/col.21889.